# Python: Why does the object in my function return differing id()'s depending on how it is called?

Tags: python

I am experimenting with calling a function with different arguments. Now I know from the Python Docs (Python Tutorial 4.7.1. Defining Functions) - that a function accumulates the arguments passed to it on subsequent calls. Because of this after the first call I was expecting the `id()` of the list object in my function to remain constant, but it does not. Why are the `id()'s` different?

```
def f(a, L=[]):
    print(id(L))
    L.append(a)
    return L

>>> f(1)

2053668960840
[1]

>>> f(1)

2053668960840
[1, 1]

>>> f(1,[9])

2053668961032
[9, 1]

>>> f(1,[9])

2053669026888
[9, 1]

>>> f(1,[9])

2053668961032
[9, 1]

>>> f(1,[9])

2053669026888
[9, 1]
```

Comment: Please include a reference to that Python doc.

Comment: when you pass an argument for `L`to the function, the printed id will be the id of the passed argument (and passing the same *value* again is not equivalent to passing the same *object*). Only when you omit the argument it will use the interal default object, which will keep its id.

Comment: Why would the ids be the same? You’re passing a new list each time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: @ScottMermelstein not a duplicate, but a good read to avoid using those mutable defaults though. Well, it's close actually... but more subtle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default argument is bound to the function upon creation, it is always the same object in memory. That's why you are seeing the same `id` whenever you call your function without providing the second argument.

When you call your function with the second argument, in your case freshly created lists, the assignment `L=<list called with>` implicitly takes place inside the function body before any other code is executed. You see the `id` of your freshly created lists in this case.

Comment: So by passing a list as my second argument, the default argument object still exists (as part of that function) but is not used because I have provided an alternative object to operate on?

Comment: @MarkH exactly!